# iOS replayKit question. default load 'Broadcast Upload Extension' when running application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, replaykit

If I run Broadcast Upload Extension scheme,

`- (void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType` Get it sampleBuffer.

but if I run application scheme, Broadcast Upload Extension is not working.

Why can't I get sampleBuffer?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast Upload Extension runs as different process name:replayKit on your case.
This process runs when you start recording.

Follow this step for start recording.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207935

If you want to break at breakpoint, Xcode -> Debug -> Attach process by PID or Name... -> specify Broadcast Upload Extension name:"replayKit"

Comment: if i build my application and install to device. after open recording.Can my program get sampleBuffer?

Comment: You should check broadcastStartedWithSetupInfo() is called. You can add NSLog() on the callback function. For getting NSLog, you need to run idevicesyslog tool.

Comment: Starting broadcast is a tricky action. You can get used by using TeamViewer. It has a helpful video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bn5L0ruk9mo